# How can WhatsApp encrypt Push Notifications on iOS?

Tags: ios, encryption, apple-push-notifications, whatsapp

Recently WhatsApp [integrated the Signal protocol](https://whispersystems.org/blog/whatsapp-complete/) for End-to-End  Encryption for all platforms.

I tried it with a friend and it said that the encryption was activated.
With the app closed and background tasks disabled on iOS 8, the push notifications from my friend still showed the message.

**Question:**
Does WhatsApp encrypt the APNS message? If yes, how do they display the text? Is there a method on iOS for processing push notifications?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Likely a better fit for http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has already been asked on security stack exchange. [How does WhatsApp's new group chat protocol work and what security properties does it have?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/119633/how-does-whatsapps-new-group-chat-protocol-work-and-what-security-properties-do)

Comment: @Liam it's more a question for iOS development IMHO. I'm asking if they encrypt the notification so if there is a way to process the push notifications on iOS as a developer.

Comment: I imagine they send a silent push and use that to trigger a fetch of the encrypted data which they then decrypt and post as a local notification

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WhatsApp could be using VoIP background mode along with PushKit for solving this problem.

VoIP pushes are:

- delivered directly to the app.
- considered high-priority notifications and are delivered without delay.
- delivered even if the app was force-quit by the user.

For details refer to [Voice Over IP (VoIP) Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/OptimizeVoIP.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015243-CH30-SW1)

Once the encrypted payload of VoIP push is decrypted they show a “Local Notification” with the decrypted message.

There is one small issue though, PushKit is available only on iOS 8 and later. So, how is Whatsapp doing it for earlier versions of iOS?
Well, it isn’t. They don’t allow you to see message preview in notifications on versions earlier that iOS 8 (Verified it on iOS 7, see screenshot)

[image: Whatsapp Settings in iOS 7]

Comment: Thanks a lot! How does PushKit also work if I disabled background updates in settings. Is it separate from that?

Comment: Are you taking about the "background app refresh" setting? It is different. VoIP pushes provide additional functionality on top of the standard push that is needed to VoIP apps to perform on-demand processing of the push before displaying a notification to the user.

Comment: Thats what I was talking about. Thanks!